# How to delete duplicate documents in MongoDB after running aggregate

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have the following aggregate that displays all the duplicates in my DB:

```
db.Articles.aggregate([
    {"$group" : { "_id": "$url", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }, 
    {"$project": {"url" : "$_id", "_id" : 0} }
]);
```

My question is, how do I delete the results after running this aggregate?

Comment: How about including the max id and then deleting rows where the url matches by the id does not.

Comment: An aggregate query returns a _cursor_, with the documents of the resulting query. You can iterate the cursor, or store the cursor documents into an array, etc. Then, process the documents - you can gather the duplicate document `_id` values and delete documents except one unique document. It also depends upon your definition of what a "duplicate" document is (it can be duplicate names, ids, or a combination of fields, etc..).